# How to increase KDE Plasma 5 icon-only task-bar icons' size?

Tags: icons, kde, plasma

I'm using Kubuntu 15.04 and Plasma 5.4. The icons on the task-manager is too [small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz1FB.png). is there a way to make them bigger?

Comment: Or in my case TOO BIG, as in taking up more than 10% of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

apparently not... the question was asked on the KDE forums months ago and nothing has changed. They are just way too small when compared to the system tray icons. If it is not too inconvenient try moving the panel to the left or right side. the thing causing them to shrink is on the vertical axis.

Comment: this answer could be improved by providing links to corroborate this